# coq --- function power definition

Tags: math, specifications, coq

I am interested in how would one define `f` to the `n` in Coq:

[image]

Basically, as an exercise, I would like to write this definition and then confirm that my
algorithm implements this specification. `Inductive` definition seems appropriate here, but I was not able to make it clean as above. What would be a clean Coq implementation of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `pow_func` function that gallais defined, you can state your specification as lemmas, such as:

```
Lemma pow_func0: forall (A:Type) (f: A -> A) (x: A), pow_fun f O x = f x.
```

and

```
Lemma pow_funcS: forall (n:nat) (A: Type) (f: A->A) (x:A), pow_fun f (S n) x = f (pow_fun f n x).
```

The proof should be trivial by unfolding the definition

Answer (score 0):

`Inductive` is used to define types closed under some operations; this is not what you are looking for here. What you want to build is a recursive function iterating over `n`. This can be done using the `Fixpoint` keyword:

```
Fixpoint pow_func {A : Type} (f : A -> A) (n : nat) (a : A) : A :=
 match n with
  | O   => f a
  | S n => f (pow_func f n a)
end.
```

If you want a nicer syntax for this function, you can introduce a `Notation`:

```
Notation "f ^ n" := (pow_func f n).
```

However, note that this is not a well-behaved definition of a notion of power: if you compose `f ^ m` and `f ^ n`, you don't get `f ^ (m + n)` but rather `f ^ (1 + m + n)`. To fix that, you should pick the base case `f ^ 0` to be the neutral element for composition `id` rather than `f` itself. Which would give you:

```
Fixpoint pow_func' {A : Type} (f : A -> A) (n : nat) (a : A) : A :=
 match n with
  | O   => a
  | S n => f (pow_func' f n a)
end.
```

Comment: This is an implementation of `power` function, which is fine. However, I would like to check that implementation against the specification I gave above, just as an exercise. The problem is that I don't know how to formalize that specification in Coq.